# gsetttings not working from inside bashrc

Tags: bash, gnome, gnome-terminal, dconf, gsettings

In my `~/.bashrc`

```bash
Terminal() {
    TerminalDarkProfile="b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9"
    TerminalLightProfile="3dd28c15-6ba4-4ba0-8289-ab023e6c88fc"

    Gsetting="org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList"
    [[ "${1}" == 'Light' ]] && gsettings set "${Gsetting}" default "${TerminalLightProfile}"
    [[ "${1}" == 'Dark' ]] && gsettings set "${Gsetting}" default "${TerminalDarkProfile}"
    gsettings get "${Gsetting}" default
}
```

If I type `Terminal Light` in bash terminal, there is no output and the Gnome terminal colour won't change.

But if I paste the function in the terminal manually:

```bash
$ Terminal() {
    TerminalDarkProfile="b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9"
    TerminalLightProfile="3dd28c15-6ba4-4ba0-8289-ab023e6c88fc"

    Gsetting="org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList"
    [[ "${1}" == 'Light' ]] && gsettings set "${Gsetting}" default "${TerminalLightProfile}"
    [[ "${1}" == 'Dark' ]] && gsettings set "${Gsetting}" default "${TerminalDarkProfile}"
    gsettings get "${Gsetting}" default
}
$ Terminal Light
'3dd28c15-6ba4-4ba0-8289-ab023e6c88fc'
```

Then, we can see that gsettings are working, and indeed the gnome terminal profile changes!

## Issue

Why is this happening? How can I change gsettings from inside  a script or bashfunction defined in `~/.bashrc`

---

## Edit

```
$ type Terminal
bash: type Terminal: command not found
$ Terminal Dark
```

I am surprised that `type Terminal: command not found` but `Terminal Dark` gives no output!

## Additionally:

```
cat Theme.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -xv
echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
whoami
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-light'
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme
```

```
$ bash ./Theme.sh 
echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
+ echo unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
whoami
+ whoami
lamy
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme 'prefer-light'
+ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-light
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme
+ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme
'prefer-light'
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme
'prefer-dark'
```

We can see that `gsettings get` immediately shows different value right after running the script!

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Please see Edit in question and 
Please see similar issue I raised here: [Gsettings does not work from inside a script - Desktop - GNOME Discourse](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/gsettings-does-not-work-from-inside-a-script/20132)

Comment: >there is no output< reload bashrc or restart bash

Comment: @yys2014 I reloaded bashrc, and rebooted my laptop, type Terminal shows the function definition but does not changes the Terminal theme!

Comment: >reloaded bashrc .. type Terminal shows the function definition< yes, it was about how to apply changes in bashrc